# Howto test logic inside a callback function with Jasmine and NodeJs to test a Mongoose controller

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jasmine

In the function below I'm retrieving an entity by id from a Mongo DB using Mongoose.

```
var Recipe = require('models/recipe').model;

exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    Recipe.findById(req.params.id, function(err, docs) {

        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }

        res.json(docs);
     });
}
```

I would like to use Jasmine to test if I return a 500 when an error has been raised and I want to test if I put the JSON entity on the reponse when everything was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating a closure containing the callback function, the advantage is that it's also reusable:

```
exports.jsonCallback = function(res) {
    return function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.json(docs);
    }
};
```

This allowed me to mock the response in a Jasmine test for the closure:

```
var resMock = {
   status : function(status) {
      return {
         send : function() {}
      }
   },
   json : function(json) {}

};

var mongooseCallback = require('controllers/callbacks/mongooseCallback').jsonCallback(resMock);

describe("when a json callback has been called", function() {

   it("should return status 500 when an error has been raised", function() {
      var returnStatusMock = { send : function() {}};
      var errorMessage = "errorMessage";

      spyOn(resMock, 'status').and.returnValue(returnStatusMock);
      spyOn(returnStatusMock, 'send');

      mongooseCallback(errorMessage, null);

      expect(resMock.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(500);
      expect(returnStatusMock.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(errorMessage);
   });

   it("should return the corresponding document in a json format", function() {
      spyOn(resMock, 'json');

      var jsonString = "{ 'name' : 'value' }";

      mongooseCallback(null, jsonString);

      expect(resMock.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jsonString);
   });

});
```